# How do I upgrade the jre of websphere server stub?

Tags: macos, java, websphere

I'm trying to connect to a remote server websphere server from my mac. I am using the websphere traditional v8.5 stub. I am able to connect to the server (my remote server is using java 8) but I am having some issues when compiling and running my code. I am getting an error saying project facet java 1.8 is not supported by WAS 8.5. I can see when I set my project facets to java 1.8 no runtimes are available. I attached the image of my project facets. I know where it says runtime compositions I need to get that up to java 1.8 instead of 1.7. I know how to do this on windows but I cannot find any info on how to do it using mac with the remote server stubs. Thanks in advance for any help[enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8muSP.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8muSP.png)

Comment: There is no such thing as 'the JRE of the WebSphere server stub'. There is the JRE that your code is executing under, and evidently you need to upgrade it, which is done in the usual way. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: based on Patrick's screenshots it's an IDE question - perhaps regarding specifying a different JRE in WDT (WebSphere Developer Toolkit)?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update your IDE.  Java 8 wasn't supported until 8.5.5.9.